# Is "Quiero he viajado a Londres" a good translation for "I want to travel to London"?

Tags: traducción, gramática

So what I want to say is:

> I want to travel to London

Is this correct?

> Quiero he viajado a Londres

Comment: And you’re conjugating both verbs...

Comment: Google translate suggests: "Quiero viajar a londres" I am not a native Spanish speaker.

Answer (score 6):

No, it isn't.

After any verb that expresses desire, such as *querer*, *desear*, *esperar*, *preferir*, *amar*, *gustar* and so on, you will always find an infinitive (at least when there is no third person involved).

In present tense:

> Yo quiero viajar a Londres.
>   Espero tener un viaje tranquilo.
>   Prefiero ir en primera clase.

In other tenses (the tricky part):

> Me gustaría viajar a Londres. (Expresses a future desire, much like "I'd like to".)
>   Preferiría haber viajado sin turbulencias. (Expresses a desire to change something in the past, so the infinitive is now a compound one.)

When a third person is involved then you need to switch to relative clauses with verbs in subjunctive mood:

> Yo quiero que Juan viaje a Londres. (I'm expressing a desire for other person.)
>   Espero que el viaje sea tranquilo. (My desire is for the trip, not for myself.)

Comment: Perhaps worth stressing that in the relative clause the verb is in the subjunctive?

Comment: @mdewey worth indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute a simpler answer to match the level of the question.

In Spanish, like in English, you conjugate the first verb and leave the second one in the infinitive:

> Quiero viajar a Londres.

**Viajar** is the infinitive form.  In English the infinitive is "to travel."  (I want **to travel**."

Note that "he viajado" is a past tense form meaning "I have traveled."